# Tkinter Login and Menu Program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Tkinter Python progarm that will have a Login page and once you are logged in it will show a Menu page for the user to interact with.

My code that includes the Quiz class, StartPage class, Menu class, difficulty class, and the Login page is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
class Quiz (tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self, *args , **kwargs):
         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args , ** kwargs)
         container = tk.Frame (self)
         container.pack (side = "top" , fill = "both" , expand = True)
         container.grid_rowconfigure (0,weight = 1)
         container.grid_columnconfigure (0,weight = 1)
         self.frames = {}
         for F in (StartPage, Menu, Difficulty):
             frame = F(container, self)
             self.frames[F] = frame
             frame.grid (row = 0, column = 0 , sticky = "nsew")
         self.show_frame(StartPage)
     def show_frame(self,cont):
         frame = self.frames[cont]
         frame.tkraise()

 class StartPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
         label = tk.Label(self, text = "Login")
         label.pack(pady = 10 , padx = 10)
         Username = tk.Entry(self)
         Username.pack()
         Password = tk.Entry (self, show = "*")
         Password.pack()
         button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Login", command = lambda: Login(Username,Password,parent,controller,self))
         button1.pack()

 class Menu(tk.Frame):
     def __init__ (self, parent, controller) :
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         label = tk.Label(self, text = "Menu")
         button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Histoy", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         button1.pack()
         button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Maths", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         button2.pack()
         button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Music",
                        command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         button3.pack()

 class Difficulty(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
         label = tk.Label(self, text = "Difficulty")
         Easy = tk.Button(self, text = "Easy", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         Easy.pack()
         Medium = tk.Button(self, text = "Medium",command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         Medium.pack()
         Hard = tk.Button(self, text = "Hard", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
         Hard.pack()
         backtomenu = tk.Button(self, text = "Back to Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Menu))
         backtomenu.pack()

 def Login(Username,Password,parent,controller,self):
     Usernames = []
     count = 0
     Username = Username.get()
     Password = Password.get()
     try:
         with open ("Usernames&Passwords.txt" , "r", encoding = "UTF-8" ) as                    file:
            for each in file:
                Usernames.append(each.strip("\n"))

except IOError as error:
    print (error)
    if Usernames[count] == Username :
         if Usernames[count + 1] == Password:
            Menu( parent, controller)
            print ("Hi")
         else:
            tm.showinfo("Username or Password is Incorrect")

     else:
          tm.showinfo("Username or Password is Incorrect")
app = Quiz()
app.geometry ("500x300")
app.mainloop()
```

When I run the code there is not an error message shown but it doesn't run the `Menu` class so it does not go to the next Tkinter Frame to continue on with the program. Can someone help point me in the right direction of why the Main class is not running. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the question. It's all we have to go on. If you're not willing to take the time to format your code properly, most people won't be willing to take the time to give you a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to destroy all other widgets before the next is shown.
Insert `self.destroy()` before Menu(parent, controller).
The same thing has to be done by the difficulty.

Edit: As @Bryan Oakley pointed out, this is the wrong solution. Instead change `Menu(parent, controller)` to `controller.show_frame(Menu)`

Comment: Thanks for that! and where abouts in the code would I need the other self.destory() in the difficulty section?

Comment: This is not the correct solution. The code shouldn't be calling `Menu(parent, controller)` inside `Login` because an instance has already been created in `Quiz`.